# Aggregate List Data from Subsites to Parent Site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to implement a project management site.  This is a simple site collection with a project portfolio parent site and several project sub-sites under this parent.  Each of the project sub-sites have an identical custom lists, "Details & Status".  The solution I am looking for is to be able to aggregate all the data from each project sub-sites "Project Details" list in the parent site

```
                         Project Management (Parent)
                              > [Aggregate List of Project Sub-Sites' "Details & Status"
    __________________________________________________________________________
    |                                |                                       |
```

Project 1 (Sub-Site)           Project 2 (Sub-Site)                    Project 3 (Sub-Site)

> "Details & Status"           > "Details & Status"                    > "Details & Status"

I am hoping the aggregate result can be formatted similar to a ListView webpart such that I can filter / sort the results from the aggregation (e.g. show only project details and status for a specific project manager, show only project details and status for projects with a specific status)

Comment: when you say aggregate data what specifically do you mean? can you make a more visual representation of your requirement or explain it in more detail since I think it should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

Bamboo List Rollup webpart does exactly what you want.  It searches subsites and displays results based on key words, list type, list names, names containing, etc etc.  It supports relative urls too, hear that MS, relative urls.  What a concept!  And, as a bonus, it actually works.  If I could get the dweebs in IT to install List Rollup our our sharepoint, I would do exactly what you are trying to do.  Another great use for an aggregator is to create a list of all documents that are checked-out to an individual and check everything in that needs to be checked in.  Honestly, unless you have some pull in IT, just put everything on a hosted site.  Then, the costs of the hosted site can be compared with the inability for IT personel to cooperate with and provide the tools necessary to the people that design and market the products that pay the bills.

Comment: If you're looking for something to give you a list of all checked out documents in a site collection I would recommend SPDash.com

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible OOB, it seems that custom codes are needed when this should be done. Do you really need to place it in a different subsite? If it is possible not to place it in separate workflows, you can just create separate lists for each of the subsites that you originally planned on creating, then create a parent list. You can sharepoint designer wherein everytime an item is added, it copies all the data in that list to the "parent list". By default, a list can be filtered very easily.

Comment: That is a very interesting solution.  The only issue I see is that since we have about 50 or so projects active at any given time, accessing the correct list and organizing all the lists might become challenging.

Comment: i've never tried this yet, nor do I know if this works in sharepoint 2013, but you could give this codeplex a shot: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ this creates extended activities that spd workflows can do or create custom activity workflow, here's a guide: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.creating-sharepoint-custom-workflow-activity-through-visual-studio-2010-en-us.aspx